# Who decided our method/style of prayer?

Tags: tefilla

I noticed recently we have very many different ways in which we emphasize our prayers. They range from the standard where the congregation recites the entire prayer and the chazzan repeats the last line, to hallel which has parts of it where lines are recited responsively line by line and parts where we even take psalms and divide them into half verses and have them recited responsively, to parts of prayer like in slichos or Yom Kippur services where the chazzan says a line and the congregation says responsive terms (sometime repeating what the chazzan said, for example Geshem, or and sometimes just adding their own responsive “בדיל ויעבר”) Who decided which form/style to use for which part? Was it the author of the prayer or did it develop later?

Comment: Regarding Hallel, see Sukkah 38a - 38b